I want to replace the leading "$$" and trailing "$$" with "(backquote)$$" and "$$(backquote)" respectively
Cause the platform I'm using only supports formulas wrapped in
`$$ and $$`

Only with backticks can it be recognized as a LateX formula.
Screenshot
I want to achieve this effect:
This is the original content:
If the object moves at a constant speed over a distance of $2L$ in a straight line within time $2t$, then the time elapsed for the object is:

$$
\tau_1 = 2t \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{L}{ct}\right)^2}
$$

The desired effect is:
If the object moves at a constant speed over a distance of $2L$ in a straight line within time $2t$, then the time elapsed for the object is:

`$$
\tau_1 = 2t \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{L}{ct}\right)^2}
$$`

I have tried writing a regular expression:
Formulas that match a single $:

(?<!\$)\$([^\$]+)\$(?!\$)

Formulas that match two $s:

(?<!\$)\$\$([^\$]+)\$\$(?!\$)

Match a $:

(?<!\$)\$(?!\$)

I have been confused for a long time and don't know how to change it. I can't find the corresponding answer on the Internet. I hope to get your help.

You can use a regex like this one: \$\$([^$]+)\$\$|\$([^$]+)\$ and put something like that as the replacement string: \$$\1$$$\2$\. A python script could do that easily.

You'd need to match the whole expression, not just the $$s at either end.  Otherwise, a regex won't help much, as $$ can be two different things.
A pattern like (\$\$([^$]|\$(?!\$))*\$\$) would work, i'd think.  (It'd match a bunch of either non-$s or $s not followed by another $, with a $$ on both ends.) You could then just replace the whole pattern you found with `$1` (replacing $1 with your regex's spelling of "the whole pattern" or "the first group") to wrap backquotes around it.

I didn't see anything saying the formula would contain $, so I'm answering based on the assumption that it won't.
The regex (\$\$[^$]*\$\$) will match the original content and replacing it with `$1` will surround it in backticks.
( - Wrap parentheses around the whole thing to match the entire body of text.
\$\$ - Find two $ at the beginning.
[^$]* - Find every character that is not a $.
\$\$ - Find two $ at the end.
) - Close the parentheses.

For matching two dollar signs, and allowing a single dollar sign in between:
(?<!\$)\$\$[^$]+(?:\$(?!\$)[^$]*)*\$\$(?!\$)

The pattern matches:

(?<!\$) Negative lookbehind, assert not $ directly to the left
\$\$ Match $$
[^$]+ Match 1 or more characters other than $
(?:\$(?!\$)[^$]*)* Optionally repeat matching $ while not directly followed by $
\$\$ Match $$
(?!\$) Negative lookahead, assert not $ directly to the right

See a regex demo.
Note that it will also match only newlines or spaces due to [^$]+ If you want to match at least a single non whitespace character other than a dollar sign you might use this regex.

For matching two dollar signs, and allowing no dollar signs in between (and the same structure for a single dollar sign pattern where \$\$ would become \$)
(?<!\$)\$\$[^$]+\$\$(?!\$)

See a regex demo

In the replacement you can use the full match between backticks. Depending on your tool or language, the notation might differ.
Some example usages referring to the full match are `$0` in PHP, `$&` in JavaScript or `\g<0>` in Python.
